# Receiving PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed exception

Tags: java, ssl, network-programming, ssl-certificate

SSL certificate presented by the broker could not be validated against the local truststore.
The set up was completely operational few days back.

Issues,
1.All of a sudden the SSL certificate presented by the JMS broker is not trusted by the client attempting to connect.

I assume that the truststore on my system, which contains trusted CA certificates, might have become corrupted or modified unintentionally.

Exception message,
03/20/2024 00:58:28.215 WARN  JmsRemoteControl: Sending component status to the JMS destination 'queue://Q_IMS_STATUS' failed due to Exception. Exception was: javax.jms.JMSException, message was: Coul[...newline]
d not connect to broker URL: ssl://localhost:61617. Reason: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed

To troubleshoot,
I rerun the build script for certificates after stopping service and ensured it is up to date, despite that nothing seem to be working as expected.

Can someone help me fix this issue please?

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? We cannot debug your system as we don't have access and I don't think the current error description is enough to go on.